# Using file extensions in image titles

Tags: images

I need to find some way to either update all the titles of my images to use the file extensions, or update the caption with all my images to be the file name.

I have over 900 images, so doing this one by one isn't really an option.  I have searched for scripts, plugins, etc, to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

The PHP function `pathinfo()` will work to get the extension for files. If your theme is just using the attachment post title for its title, then loop through all post types of 'attachment', and/or post mime/type that contains 'image' and then use pathinfo to get the file extension and update the title based on that.